# Loading image in lower quality in WP7?

Tags: c#, performance, image, windows-phone-7

Is it possible when loading an image from Isolated Storage to load it in lower quality format? I'm looping through a list of file paths that point to an image in Isolated Storage.

For example here is my code right now:

```
myObjectsList[i].ImageSrc = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
```

Eventually the code runs fine, but it takes extremely long to load just 6 images and I'm hitting around 250mb (which is way over the limit for lower end devices). So what I was trying to figure out is if it's possible to load the images in a lower quality format. Or of course if anyone has any other suggestions I'd appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Is it possible to load an image, convert it to a thumbnail, then dispose of the large image before moving onto the next one?  No idea about performance (probably worse than just straight up loading all of them) but at least it should solve the memory issue.  EDIT: Perhaps you can use a different implementation than PictureDecoder.  WriteableBitmapEx can read JPEGs and is WP7 compatible: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save your images create thumbnails of your images and load them for preview. This is a standard solution for this kind of problems.

I don't know if it's possible to load lower quality images, but it won't help you with your memory issue.

Comment: Actually it did work. Memory consumption dropped by over 100mb. It turns out you not only have to lower quality but the height and width. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: loyalpenguin - you managed to load lower quality images from high quality images stored in isolated storage? Could you please share the code?